# How do I change the format of a field in an OpenIso8583.Net message

Tags: c#, openiso8583.net

For example, the default format for field 128 in `OpenIso8583Rev93` is Fixed Hex 8.  How would I change it to Fixed Hex 16.

Comment: This question pertains to my OSS library http://code.google.com/p/openiso8583net/.  That is why I have answered it

Comment: The tag openiso8583.net is intentional.  It is a new library and I hope to have more questions here in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend Iso8583Rev93 and override the template class in the constructor.

```
public class Iso8583Extended : Iso8583Rev93
{
    private static readonly Template ExtendedTemplate;
    static Iso8583Extended()
    {
        ExtendedTemplate = new Template();
        ExtendedTemplate[Bit._128_MAC] = FieldDescriptor.AsciiFixed(16, FieldValidators.Hex);
    }

    public Iso8583Extended():base(ExtendedTemplate)
    {
    }
}
```

Will do the job.